# Should I file every stock I sell when I do my tax report?

Tags: taxes, stocks, capital-gains-tax, ireland

As a way of saving money for future I started investing into the stock market 1.5 years ago. I do not think much of it, I usually play around rather than treating this seriously. I didn't invest much of my savings, only around €6000. Even with me  messing around and buying risky stocks I still manage to get more than 10% interest on my initial capital per year.

The website of [Citizen's information](https://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/money_and_tax/tax/capital_taxes/capital_gains_tax.html) states:

> The first €1,270 of taxable gains in a tax year are exempt from CGT.

I haven't yet made more than than in any given tax year. Do I still need to file all my transactions I have made in that tax year with the Tax office? What if next year I make more than 1270 euros in profit? Should I submit every single transaction I made?

Answer (score 1):

You should report it. The tax man will come for you if you're found to have been cheating. What happens if you don't file, but then you forgot that you actually made an extra 1000 that year? The government will take that and more out of your hide for cheating them.

The majority of investing firms will automatically generate the relevant tax reporting documents for your region. It should be trivial to enter the values from that form into your taxes.